# Replace Next Line by <br> in the String Obtained from TextBox

Tags: c#, .net

I need to replace New Line with `<br>` in the string obtained from a text box.Currently i use this

```
string text= textbox.Text;
text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
```

But nothing is getting replaced when i test using `MessageBox.show(text);`

Comment: Hint: strings are ***immutable***

Comment: @CodyGray Im using the answer from that question you marked as duplicate.It does not work.

Comment: Well, that's the point of the hint. You cannot simply do `text.Replace(...)` because strings are immutable. That code will *not* modify `text`, it will return a *new* string. You have to do `text = text.Replace(...)`.

Comment: @CodyGray okay.. i get your point now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Replace` **returns** a `string`. Do this:

```
string text= textbox.Text;
text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br>"); //note the text = ...
```

You are almost there, except what you do in your code isn't returning the result of your `string.Replace`.

Comment: Thanks.. i understand that i need to assign it explicitly since strings are immutable.